# I want to paste two csv files in a new file

Tags: linux, paste

I want to paste two csv files in a new file,

File one has following content:

Nick  <50

sam  >80

File two has following  content:

3452

3423

I want new file to be like this:
Nick  <50 3452
sam  >80  3423

I have used **paste -d' ' temp-other.csv temp-age.csv> new.csv**  but i get following reult in new csv file:

Nick  <50 3452

sam  >80 3423

i tried the same thing in text file. I get something like this:

Nick  <50 3452 sam  >80  3423

How can i correct this? This is a part of a script file, so I cant use awk or sed. This is a sample of what i wanted to do. The actual script file looks as follwing.

## !/bin/bash

TRAIN=100

VALID=100

TEST=100

tail -n +13 student.arff|\

fgrep -v "%" | shuf |

sed -e"s/,/ /g" > temp1.csv

cut  -f1 -d' ' temp1.csv >temp-age.txt

cut -d' ' -f2- temp1.csv>temp-other.txt

paste -d' ' temp-other.txt temp-age.txt > temp1.txt

## The training file

/bin/echo "SNNS pattern definition file V3.2"  >student.pat

/bin/echo "generated at Mon Apr 25 15:58:23 1994"  >>student.pat

/bin/echo "No. of patterns : $TRAIN"  >>student.pat

/bin/echo "No. of input units : 25"  >>student.pat

/bin/echo "No. of output units : 5"  >>student.pat

head -$TRAIN temp1.txt |

sed -e"s/male/1 0 /g" |

sed -e"s/female/ 0 1/g" |>student1.train

Comment: To connect all the lines into one you can delete all the linefeeds.  Look at `tr` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132835

Answer (score 0):

```
paste -d' ' temp-other.csv temp-age.csv | paste -d' ' -s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat f1
Nick <50
sam >80

$ cat f2
3452
3423

# joining using paste
$ paste -d' ' f1 f2
Nick <50 3452
sam >80 3423

# another method to join using pr
$ pr -mtJS' ' f1 f2
Nick <50 3452
sam >80 3423

# This is what you want probably, this doesn't give newline
$ paste -d' ' f1 f2 |  tr -s '\n' ' '
Nick <50 3452 sam >80 3423

# if you want newline use another paste
$ paste -d' ' f1 f2 | paste -d' ' -s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 paste -d ' ' f1 f2 | paste -d ' ' - -
```

**Output:**

```
Nick <50 3452 sam >80 3423
```

Comment: @Pradeep-Pallegama : `paste -d ' ' - - ` will ensure you have each record sepeared by new line. If you don't want this then you can probably try ` - - - -`

Comment: You can edit your answer to improve its quality rather than commenting on it.

Comment: @Lucas  ?? What's the matter dude.